# Noda Timezone issue with IDateTimeZoneSource.MapTimeZoneId

Tags: c#, vb.net, timezone, nodatime

I am trying to convert Windows to IANA time zone and below is the code that works most of the time. But when the *windows time id = "Turks & Caicos"* then below code *returns NULL*. I am using [NODATIME](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime/) Version **1.3.1**

```
    Public Function ConvertID_WindowsToIana(strWindowsZoneID As String) As String
        If strWindowsZoneID.Equals("UTC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            Return "Etc/UTC"
        End If

        Dim tzdbSource = NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.[Default]
        Dim tzi = TimeZoneInfo.MapTimeZoneId(strWindowsZoneID)
        Return tzdbSource.CanonicalIdMap(tzi)
    End Function
```

Here when tzi = -4:00 Turks & Caicos, in this case the return is NULL.

Now when I updated to version 2.2.3, thought that it will fix the stuff, but as per the documentation

[image]

And now that function is taking a "Position Of Current String" as parameter.

So my code will look like below:

```
  Public Function ConvertID_WindowsToIana(strWindowsZoneID As String) As String

        Dim tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(strWindowsZoneID)
        Dim tzid = tzdbSource.GetSystemDefaultId(WHAT TO PUT HERE)
        // some logic
    End Function
```

**Question 1:** Why my first code does not work for "Turks and Caicos".

**Question 2:** I updated thinking it will fix that issue, but now that function is vanished and replaced, and I don't know what to use. Please help me.

**P.S:** For Eastern and many other time zones the **First Code Snippet** works fine.

Comment: Do you mean you updated to 2.2.3? That's the current version.

Comment: @JonSkeet: My bad. I added a typo section in my question.

Comment: Rather than just note the typo, please just fix it - there's no need to mention 3.1.1 at all.

Comment: Done. Some people in SO don't like editing that way as it makes their original comment obsolete. Anyways I made the changes. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have added my complete function in first code snippet. Can you have a look once. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I added an answer several minutes ago, and then updated it...

Comment: You should really revert your previous edit though - because you've entirely changed away from using MapTimeZoneId at all. Your claim that "Eastern and many other time zones" work with the first snippet is no longer correct, as it's only ever going to use the default system zone. (You're not using `tzi`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160809/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetSystemDefaultId` doesn't replace all the functionality of `MapTimeZoneId` - you don't want to call that here.

Instead, use `tzdbSource.WindowsMapping` to get a `WindowsZones` that you can then use to find the TZDB ID. Here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var source = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default;

        string windowsId = "Turks And Caicos Standard Time";

        var mapping = source.WindowsMapping.PrimaryMapping;
        if (mapping.TryGetValue(windowsId, out string tzdbId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Mapped to {tzdbId}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        }
    }    
}
```

An alternative approach is to use Matt Johnson's [TimeZoneConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter/) package, which can simplify things a bit more. If you're using Noda Time elsewhere, it probably makes sense to stick with Noda Time, but if you're *only* using it for time zone ID conversion, TimeZoneConverter is a better choice.

As for why "Turks and Caicos" doesn't work - I assume you mean "Turks And Caicos Standard Time" as the ID. That was only introduced into the CLDR mapping data in CLDR v30, which was released over a year later than 1.3.1. If you update to 1.3.5 or 1.4.2, both of those should be fine.

Comment: Worked like a charm!